# add lines in realtime with preg_replace

Tags: php, string, function, preg-replace, eof

I was wondering if it's possible to fetch the regular expression match in preg_replace and manipulate it in real time (iow... at the same preg_replace command)...

This is not the proper syntax but just to get the idea...

```
    $test = <<<EOF

    <!--

    THIS IS COMMENT #1

    -->

    <!--

    THIS IS COMMENT #2

    -->
    EOF;

    $test = preg_replace('#<--(.|\s)*?-->#', 'Additional line to the html comment without delete the real comment' . '#<--(.|\s)*?-->#' .'<BR/>' , $test);

    //iow... how can I replace this '#<--(.|\s)*?-->#'
//to this : 'Additional line to the html comment without delete the real comment' . '#<--(.|\s)*?-->#' .'<BR/>'

    echo $test;

    /*
    I expect to get this :

    <!--
    Additional line to the html comment without delete the real comment
    THIS IS COMMENT #1

    -->

    <!--
    Additional line to the html comment without delete the real comment
    THIS IS COMMENT #2

    -->
    */
```

Any idea? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$test = preg_replace('#(<--)(.+?)(-->)#', '$1Additional line to the html comment without delete the real comment$2$3' , $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your comments have always two newlines at the begining, a quick way without regex:

```
$trans = array("<!--\n\n" => "<!--\n$newline",
               "<!--\r\n\r\n" => "<!--\r\n$newline");

$str = strtr($str, $trans);
```

Comment: Looks like a great solution but not working (or am I doing something wrong ?) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9bde11b5b57e9463fd21e79198e20c41b772ae0f